# Как сверстать данный кусок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, background

Добрый вечер господа, есть такая часть макета, как сверстать правильнее. Контент который по центру в wrapper'e который имеет макс ширину 1200. А вот этот background image должен тянуться до краях браузера( пример скриншота вся ширина 1920). Эти картинки и линий это один .png файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<div class="wrapper"><div class="container">...</div><img src="" alt=""></div>`

Comment: надеюсь "линий" - речь не про сетку, ибо это явно не может быть в одной пнг (если дизайнер в своем уме)

Comment: нее, это сетка для Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cпособ 1.** Сделайте множественный background.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/100), url(http://lorempixel.com/500/200), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
  background-position: 100% 0, 0 100px, 100% 300px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  /* 1200px */
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

**Cпособ 2.** Рассчитайте позицию изображения.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px; /* 1200px */
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vw;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300">
</div>
```